# Принцип наследования в html/css

Tags: html, css

Почему в таком html-файле:

```
<body>
<div class="intro">
    
</div>
</body>
```

Такой CSS-файл убирает отступы "фонового цвета"

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}


.intro {
    height: 596px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #87509C;
}
```

А другой — нет

```
.intro {
    height: 596px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #87509C;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, вы убираете отступы у `body`, который изначально имеет отступы по-умолчанию в 8px. А блок `.intro` занимает всю ширину body, но не выходит за его пределы

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}


.intro {
    height: 596px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #87509C;
}
```

Во втором кейсе, меняются отступы у `.intro`, а у `body` остаются стандартные `8px`. Блок `.intro' занимает весь блок` body`, но не выходит за его пределы, поэтому остаются отступы на "заднем фоне"

```
.intro {
    height: 596px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #87509C;
}
```

Для сброса стандартных стилей для тегов body и html можно использовать что-то подобное:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Мой код приемлем для удаления отступов? Или стоит сделать по-другому?

Comment: Да, можно так сбросить стили по умолчанию,  добавил в ответ.  При желании можно добавить и другие атрибуты для сброса